# How do you make a calculator in c++ using switch case and while loop?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

The calculator is made to run once using the switch case but i wanted to use while loop for if you type a wrong operator it wouldn't restart all over again but just ask you to retype the correct operator and then loop again until you quit.

```
float z,y,z;
char err 'c',opp;

while (err !='q')
{
cout<<"enter value for x ";
cin>>x;
cout<<"enter value for y ";
cin>>y;

cout<<"enter + for addition";
cout<<"enter - for subtraction";
cout<<"enter * for multiplication";
same for divison
cout<<"enter r to restart"<<endl;
cout<<"enter q to quit"<<endl;

cin>>opp;
err = 'u';
switch(opp)
```

and then you get the case and break for all the operators, for restart and quit,

```
case 'r'
cout<<"restarting "<<endl;
break;
case 'q'
cout<<"quitting "<<endl;
err ='q';
break;
```

but how do i made it loop using a while loop so it doesn't make me repeat the values but just asks me to retype the operator?

I'm sorry, but i didn't write this code, a teacher of min did, he asked us to use exactly what he typed but use while loop, he asked us not to change x, y or z or anything and i know he didn't initialize err and I'm so confused, i don't understand the code

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: It'd make a lot more sense to use a `bool` instead of some arbitrary `char` to terminate your loop.

Comment: You have one while loop for the whole expression, two values and an operator. If you also want to ask again for just the operator, then you need **another** while loop inside the first one. That inner while loop just repeats asking for an operator until the user enters a valid operator.

Comment: x, y, and z (or in your case: z, z, y) are terrible names. I will not understand the draw that `float` has on new learners. `err` is not properly initialized. Please take the time to learn about the [mre]. And your formatting is garbage.

Answer (score 1):

This homework shall teach you how to do input validation.

The C++ iostream library will help you.

And, you must check always each IO operation for potential errors. For that reason streams, like `std::cin` have a state. You can acces this with the so called state functions. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios).

Especially useful are the [operator!](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) and the [operator bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). They will show you, if the stream, after an IO operation is still in good state or not.

For example, if you open a file with `std:istream ifs("text.txt);`, then you can simply write `if (!ifs)` to detect an error or `if (ifs)` to see, if the result was good. This works with all stream operations.

Additionally, you can also write something like `if (std::cin >> x)` to check, if the user input was ok.

You may expect an `integer`, but the user will type "abc". This mechanisms works, because the extration operator `>>` returns again a reference to the stream. So,  `if (std::cin >> x)` will end up similar like `if (std::cin)`. And then the bool operator for the stream will be used to get the state.

For the other input validations, e.g., if an operator is valid, we can simply use boolean expressions. We embed everything in a loop and continue the loop, unitl we get a valid input.

The result could be a code like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {

    bool inputError = true;
    bool doOperate = true;
    while (doOperate) {


        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        float z = 0;
        char oper = '\0';


        do {
            std::cout << "\n\n\nPlease enter value for operand x: ";
            inputError = not(std::cin >> x);
            if (inputError) {
                std::cout << "\nError: Problem with given input\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        } while (inputError);
        do {
            std::cout << "\nPlease enter value for operand y: ";
            inputError = not(std::cin >> y);
            if (inputError) {
                std::cout << "\nError: Problem with given input\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        } while (inputError);
        do {
            std::cout << "\nPlease enter operator. Either + or - or * or /: ";
            inputError = (not(std::cin >> oper) or (oper != '+' and oper != '-' and oper != '*' and oper != '/'));
            if (inputError) {
                std::cout << "\nError: Problem with given input\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        } while (inputError);
        switch (oper) {
        case '+':
            std::cout << "\n\nThe result of x + y = " << (x + y) << '\n';
            break;
        case '-':
            std::cout << "\n\nThe result of x - y = " << (x - y) << '\n';
            break;
        case '*':
            std::cout << "\n\nThe result of x * y = " << (x * y) << '\n';
            break;
        case '/':
            if (y == 0)
                std::cout << "\n\nError: Division by 0 not allowed\n";
            else
                std::cout << "\n\nThe result of x / y = " << (x / y) << '\n';
            break;
        default:
            std::cerr << "\n\nError: Internal Error. Stopping program . . .";
            doOperate = false;
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n\nDo you want to continue? Then enter   y\n";
        char selection = '\0';
        if (not((std::cin >> selection) and (selection == 'y')))
            doOperate = false;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\nLeaving program . . .\n\n";
}
```

Please note: Nobody would write in reality such repeating blocks in the code and use functions instead.

Second note: After a stream is in error state, we need to [clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) that state and [remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) potential invalid characters from the input stream